# How to use $addFields (aggregation) only when a certain condition is met

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to add field only when a certain condition is met, for example, if an array size > 0 then use `$addFields` to add field "date", otherwise don't add it.

- when using `$cond` its a boolean so I have to add a field with either date value or false
- When using `if` I have to provide `else`, `then` conditions

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in MongoDB 3.6, you can use the variable [$$REMOVE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-conditionally) in aggregation expressions to conditionally suppress a field. For an example, see [Conditionally Exclude Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields),

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $cond: [
          { $gt: [{ $size: "$array" }, 0] },
          "date field", // your date field
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zbB8zwem_-Y)

Comment: Thanks very much! didn't know you could use "$$REMOVE"